# If I compare the first and second element in a list, how do I make it stop on the last one? [simple scheme q]

Tags: scheme, logic

I'm a beginner with scheme and I am a little confused with the logic:

Lets say I wanted the biggest number from a list and I had to use (first ns) and (second ns)

so the expression would consist of:

```
(define (bigger ns)
        (cond
            .....
               ((> (first ns)(second ns) (cons.....(bigger (rest ns)))...))
```

If I am always comparing the first element to second element in the list, once it reaches the last element of the list, there will no longer be a second element available, and this brings up an error. How do I stop it at the last one? After all, there is no last? function to use.

Answer (score 1):

A quick recap of how lists work in Scheme, so it might help your confusion more generally:

A *pair* is two things, a `first` and a `rest`.  Often it's written with a dot like this: `(1 . 2)`

A *list* is either the empty list, which is also named `null`, or it's a pair whose second thing (its `rest`) is a list.

So if you have a list of numbers like this: `(1 2 3 4 5)` recall that it's actually a series of nested pairs:
`(1 . (2 . (3 . (4 . (5 . null)))))`

So, if you're recursing down the series of pairs, when you get to the last one, you'll know that it's the end because the `rest` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

When `(null? (rest ns))`, you're at the last element, the maximum is the present element `(first ns)` and you can stop the recursion.